# Visual Studio raises an error when connecting to iMac

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

I have just updated Visual Studio to the latest Version 17.9.3. Now, I'm working on a `NET8` `MAUI` project. When I try to connect my Visual Studio for Windows to the iMac, I get this error:

> Could not install workload 'ios'. Details: Unhandled exception:
> Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadManifestCompositionException:
> Could not find workload 'ios' extended by workload 'maui-ios' in
> manifest 'microsoft.net.sdk.maui'
> [/Users/enrico/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/sdk-manifests/8.0.100/microsoft.net.sdk.maui/8.0.3/WorkloadManifest.json]    at
> Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadResolver.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<g__EnumerateWorkloadWithExtendsRec|0>d.MoveNext()
> at
> Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadResolver.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<g__EnumerateWorkloadWithExtendsRec|0>d.MoveNext()

[image]

Is there a way to fix this issue?

### Update

I tried to update the workload on my iMac with

```
sudo dotnet workload install maui
```

After that, I get the same error.

### Update

After copying the folder from my Windows laptop to the iMax, I get this issue

[image]

Comment: See this issue - https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20686

Comment: Had  the same issue yesterday and also followed the workaround metionend in the Github issue, but it did not work for me. I solved it by rolling VS back to version 17.9.2.

Comment: Had the same issue. It works with Visual Studio 17.10.0 Preview 2.0 and Xcode 15.2.

Comment: you can try [deleting the XMA cache folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting#clearing-the-broker-idb-build-and-designer-agents-on-the-mac) to force Visual Studio to re-upload them.